# Xamarin Pass data from a viewModel to another

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm not able to pass data from one ViewModel to another.
I try a lot of thing but nothing work.
So what's ive done so far

On my LoginViewModel I have this code to get info from the database

```
 CRUD crud = new CRUD();
 UserLogin = crud.Login(UserName, Password);       
 Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
 await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}?UserLogin={UserLogin}");
```

On My HomePage I try a lot of thing.
This is what I have now on the homepage: ContentPage

```
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public HomePage(List<User> UserLogin)
        {
            
            this.BindingContext = new HomeViewModel(UserLogin);
        }
      
    }
```

I try to move the InitializeCompognent(), Remove it, remove the base constructor but I have blank page or a error. That's the only way I get a page loaded.
On the HomeViewModel I have this code

```
 public class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public List<User> UserLogin { get;}

        public HomeViewModel() { }

        public HomeViewModel(List<User> Users)
        {
            Title = "Acceuil";
            UserLogin = Users;
        }
    }
```

When I debug I I stop in the Login view Model await Shell.Curent...I check the HomeViewModel UserLogin and I have my data. But it seem's to wipe it out when the page is loaded after.
Can somebody help me having the data on the HomeViewModel page please.
Thanks.
Jc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554375/xamarin-forms-4-shell-navigation-with-complex-parameters

Comment: So If I understand there's no way to do it easy? I don't get it. C# is oriented object of course and I can't pass a object whithout some complicated tricks??

Comment: there are a LOT of ways you can approach it.  User login data could be stored as a property of the App class so it is available universally.  If you don't use shell navigation you have more control over how data is passed when navigating.  Or there is a project linked in that other question that has a way to do it with Shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the document of [pass data in shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data):

> To receive data, the class that represents the page being navigated
> to, or the class for the page's BindingContext, must be decorated with
> a `QueryPropertyAttribute` for each query parameter

In your HomePage, it should have a property like this:

```
[QueryProperty("myUserLogin", "UserLogin")]
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public List<User> myUserLogin { get; set; }

    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And you should not remove `InitializeCompognent()` as it is responsible for loading codes in Xaml.

**Second solution**:

Declare a property in App class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static List<User> UserLogin { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

Then in your `LoginViewModel`, get the data:

```
 App.UserLogin = crud.Login(UserName, Password);
```

You don't  need to pass it to HomePage, in the HomePage, you can get it by:

```
public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    List<User> myUserData = App.UserLogin;
}
```