# How to pass complex objects to a new page using shell?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Recently I've started using shell and I noticed an improvement in page transitioning and a bug I was facing using NavigationPage was fixed just by replacing it with shell.

So I was excited to use it.

However soon after I realized I can't send objects from page to page through shell like I could using a constructer of a page.
I searched a bit and now know that shell passes strings only.
I turned the object into JSON but then faced an exception due to long URI length.

Honestly, I am disappointed. I thought something this important would be implemented in shell...
but In any case, how do you guys work around this?

Comment: does this help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin forms 4 shell navigation with complex parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554375/xamarin-forms-4-shell-navigation-with-complex-parameters)

Comment: @ShubhamTyagi This explains how to pass simple strings only

Comment: @Cfun

Thank you for this.
There seems to be a custom implementation for this by someone however I am feeling reluctant to use it because it might come with unknown errors.

A good news though is someone has started working on this on github five days ago

Comment: @Maho I don't think you have an easy option right now a part from json, or you can wait until XF team implements this enhancement https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6848

Comment: @Cfun yeah, it's pretty cool that they're working on it, unfortunately, that might take some time since they just started so maybe I would have to change my code a bit to remove the need for direct passing of the object needed.
Maybe passing an id/unique value for the item and retrieving it from the database in the new page's constructer through that id

Comment: @Maho Yeah that could be a working idea